# Babinet's principle

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, diffraction

I am reading a paper on creating ponderomotive traps for neutral atoms.

The setting is that we consider the far-field (Fraunhofer) diffraction pattern of the input field

$$E_i(\rho) = A_0 e^{-(\rho^2/\omega^2)}\times e^{i\phi(\rho)}$$
with $$
\phi(\rho) = 
\begin{cases}
\pi , & \rho \leq R \\
0,  & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

Instead of calculating the integral directly, the authors invoke [Babinet's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babinet%27s_principle). They say that

> According to Babinet’s principle, one can combine the individual fields generated from complementary screens that are arriving at some point to find the unobstructed field

I understand this statement. From this, they deduce

> Choosing from an incident Gaussian field a pi-shifted disk and an unshifted annulus that each contain half of the electric field creates a region of zero intensity at the focus. The magnitudes of the individual fields are equal but their phases are opposite, resulting in complete destructive interference. By changing the size of the Pi-region, or by changing the incident beam size, one can tune the depth of the minimum.

I don't see how this follows from Babinet's principle. Any help is appreciated.